# testing using selenium: chrome screensharing auto select tab and share with audio

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, screensharing, web-mediarecorder, google-chrome-flags

I am testing my website using Selenium and I am able to open chrome with `--auto-select-desktop-capture-source="tab_name"` and select the tab when screen share is enabled. Now I want the audio playing in the tab to be in my stream along with the video. While doing it manually there is a checkbox which enables audio sharing but is there something which can help enable it from Selenium?

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/john_vera/yr2k9xob/5/
Notice the Share Audio checkbox after selecting chrome tab in the dialog. I want to check that from Selenium.

Comment: Any news on that front?

Answer (score 4):

You could create an custom chromium build and implement an bypass for this dialog. To build chromium you can use these instructions (for windows): [Here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md)

Here the bypass in file display_media_access_handler.cc:

Look for this line:

```
// Orignal code
pending_request.picker->Show(picker_params, std::move(source_lists), std::move(done_callback));
```

And replace it with this

```
// Bypass dialog
content::DesktopMediaID screenSource(content::DesktopMediaID::TYPE_SCREEN, content::DesktopMediaID::kNullId, web_contents);
screenSource.audio_share = true;

OnPickerDialogResults(web_contents, screenSource);
// End of bypass
```

I testet it with Chromium Version 84.

Comment: I tried to build Chromium version 83 on Mac and 85 on Ubuntu with  `content::DesktopMediaID::TYPE_WEB_CONTENTS`, but while testing i am getting the following error :

`Error starting tab capture`

Is there anything else I should be changing?

Comment: @Nija I think that if you change the type to TYPE_WEB_CONTENTS chrome needs to know the tab which should be shared, the following parameters may need to be changes also. You can try to add log-messages to the dialog to find out the right parameters for sharing a browser tab and adapt the code accordingly. I did the same for sharing the whole desktop.